# Is CF 6.1 compatible with IIS7?

Tags: iis-7, coldfusion

Is it advisable to install CF 6.1 on IIS 7 or is it compatible with IIS7 to begin with?

I did a J2EE Multiserver type installation of CF 6.1 and specified IIS as web server but without any luck, I am getting the following error:

HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Detailed Error Information
Module IIS Web Core 
Notification MapRequestHandler 
Handler StaticFile 
Error Code 0x80070002 
Requested URL http://127.0.0.1:80/CFIDE/administrator/index.cfm 
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CFIDE\administrator\index.cfm 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous

Comment: I'd be surprised if it is nto compatible to work, but I would also be surprised if the auto-config tool in the installer (or separately) would configure it properly.  I would suspect you'd have to do it manually.  Sorry I can't be more help than that.

Comment: Yea am stuck too..any other help guys

Comment: Please do not repost questions, and please do not have more than one active account on the system.

Comment: FlexyBoz - I think you forgot to switch accounts. You stated on 'I am stuck too' on a post you made. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the web server configuration tool - I believe the Windows executable is wsconfig.exe. From there its fairly intuitive on how to proceed.

Also, try following the instructions here, http://www.communitymx.com/content/article.cfm?page=1&cid=224AA . I know its for CF 7, but it may work with Cf 6.1.

Comment: Hello Scott,

I reinstalled IIS with everything ticked. Then I installed CF6.1 as self contained server.

I have done exactly the requested changes as stated in communitymx link above. However I am now getting the Error 404.17.

Could you tell me if I missed anything (though I know I didnt miss any step as I checked things more than twice). Or is there any other minor change that needs to be done?

Thanks again.